# Template argument list short circuit?

Tags: c++, templates

I have class similar to `integral_constant` that takes as parameter compile time boolean constexpr. Now I want to create `is_signed` trait, that should check whether `is_integral<T>` evaluates to true and if it does, I will check whether `T(-1) < T(0)`.

Will this trait work for any given type or will it fail upon type that can not be constructed with -1 and 0 values? In other words, are constexpr boolean expressions in template parameter list short-circuited?

Comment: You cold always see how [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) implements [`is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) from [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't "short circuit", because the expression still must be valid even if it's not actually evaluated, so you'll need to add a layer of indirection.

One possible solution:

```
namespace details {
    // primary template for integrals
    template<class T, bool = is_integral<T>::value>
    struct is_signed_integral_impl : std::integral_constant<bool, T(-1) < T(0)> {};

    // not integral
    template<class T>
    struct is_signed_integral_impl<T, false> : std::false_type {};
}

template<class T>
struct is_signed_integral : details::is_signed_integral_impl<T> {};
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of delayed evaluation is the reason for [`mpl::eval_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/eval-if-c.html):

```
template <typename T>
struct check_minus_1
    : std::integral_constant<bool, T(-1) < T(0)>
{ };


template <typename T>
struct is_signed 
    : mpl::eval_if_c<is_integral<T>::value,
                     check_minus_1<T>,
                     std::false_type>::type
{ };
```

`check_minus_1` is only valid for integral types, but will only be instantiated if `is_integral<T>::value` evaluates to `true`.